# Why doesn't Chrome allow changing of style tag via JS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome

I'm running this code:

```
    jQuery.get("http://email.hackmailer.com/checkuser.php?email=".concat(document.getElementById('name').value).concat(document.getElementById('domain').value), function(data) {
        if(data == "true") {
            document.getElementById('containerThree').style = "background-color:#20bb47;";
        }else{
            document.getElementById('containerThree').style = "background-color:#b33535;";
        }
        document.getElementById('avail').style = "color:#272727;";
        document.getElementById('emt').style = "color:#272727;";
    });
```

It works fine in FireFox, but in chrome not at all. I've tried using `.style.background = "#mycolorcode"` but it still doesn't work in chrome(and in that case, firefox too).

Comment: `.style.backgroundColor = "#mycolorcode"`, as long as it is inline style. For CSS, you need `getComputed`.

Comment: Minor point: your question title may be inaccurate, as you seem to be talking about changing the style *attribute*, rather than the tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
if (data === 'true') {
  document.getElementById('containerThree').style.backgroundColor = '#20bb47';
} else {
  document.getElementById('containerThree').style.backgroundColor = '#b33535';
}
```

http://devdocs.io/html/element/style

http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/

NOTE: `'true'` is a string. You would most likely would rather use the Boolean `true`.

**Based on the latest edit to your question**, does this cleanup of your surrounding code help?

```
jQuery.get('http://email.hackmailer.com/checkuser.php?email='
           .concat(document.getElementById('name').value)
           .concat(document.getElementById('domain').value), 

            function (data) {

              if (data === true) {
                document.getElementById('containerThree').style.backgroundColor = '#20bb47';
              } else {
                document.getElementById('containerThree').style.backgroundColor = '#b33535';
              }

              document.getElementById('avail').style.color = '#272727';
              document.getElementById('emt').style.color = '#272727';

});
```

Comment: Doesn't work in either firefox or chrome. It's a <div> if it makes any difference.

Comment: That's odd. The demo doesn't work, or this code in your codebase isn't working? Here's a screenshot of what I see: http://imgur.com/a/V6sfm

Comment: I tried it on my site, and it didn't work. I realized what inline style is, I have the div in question assigned a class with background-color and min-height set. I tried removing background color and trying this approach, no change.

Comment: Are you sure you should be using `'true'` and not `true`?

Comment: `data === true` is not required. mentioning just `data` enough. if you are considering `true` as boolean.

Comment: @Mr_Green: In most cases, sure. But OP didn't give much context; what if `data` exists but is falsey? Regardless, that detail is not likely the cause of OP's error.

Comment: @janaspage The information was for you but not OP. I don't mind you even don't edit it. but that expression was irking me, so thought to inform you.

Comment: Still doesn't work. The issue is in the JS in some way.

Comment: Sorry to hear. Could you be more specific? Is the setting of color not working, is the `get` not working, or is some other desired behavior not working? Is any error thrown? What is the value of `data`?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to send a string as 'true' to check a condition. Use it like:

```
var data = true; //use boolean but not 'true' as string.
```

Then you can simple use it as follows:

```
jQuery.get("http://email.hackmailer.com/checkuser.php?email=" + document.getElementById('name').value + document.getElementById('domain').value, function(data) {
    var colorValue = "#272727";
    document.getElementById('containerThree').style.backgroundColor = data == "true"?"#20bb47":"#b33535";
    document.getElementById('avail').style.color = colorValue;
    document.getElementById('emt').style.color = colorValue;
});
```

BTW, I am not sure how `.style = "background-color:#20bb47;";` is working for you.

Comment: @user3618509 doesn't matter. it shouldn't work. unless you are using javascript. can you please clarify or post the related code? (_more, I mean_)

Comment: @user3618509 check my updated post. also please do debug using `console.log` between each step.

Comment: Better than `console.log`, try the `debugger` keyword. It's shorter to type, and it allows you to inspect every value. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/debugger

Comment: I tried debugging, nothing outputs. The website in question is http://www.hackmailer.com/ You can view the JS code in the webpage source.